# Using Imagick to convert PDF in landscape format to image

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I'm using Imagick to convert PDFs to images. It works great when I convert PDFs oriented in portrait mode. When I try with PDFs in landscape mode, the result is a cropped image. Even if I try `rotateImage("#fff",90)`, the result is also cropped.

Here's the important part of my script:

```
  $imagick = new \Imagick();
  $imagick->setResolution(144, 144);
  $imagick->readImage(sprintf('%s[%s]', $this->pdfFile, $this->page - 1));
  $imagick->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
  $imagick->setFormat($this->determineOutputFormat($pathToImage));
  return $imagick;
```

Could anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Please can you post an example PDF.

Comment: did you find any solution so far?

Comment: I don't know the PHP API, but maybe there is an equivalent to the `-auto-orient` command line option which helps in your case.